# Vue bindings and CSS in HTML does not work

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to display vue within an HTML. It worked properly with the vue cli but now that I am trying to integrate it in a bare HTML file, CSS doesn't work properly anymore. It might as well has to do with the bindings of vue since the shown bar should repeat three time, but is only shown once.
I don't get any error in the console so I'm clueless.
Any help is appreciated!

[result of html atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBU18.png)

[how it looked like with vue cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JGfK.png)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <title>vue demo</title>     
    <style type="text/css">
    html,
      #app{
        font-family: Helvetica;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1;
        background-color: rgb(221, 229, 230);
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }

      .switch {
          background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          padding: 4px;
          white-space: nowrap;
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 4px;
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          text-align: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 100%;
          vertical-align: middle;
          margin-right: 20px;
      }

      .switch.closed {
          background-image: url(switch-closed.svg);
          background-position: 0px 0px;
      }

      .switch.opened {
          background-image: url(switch-opened.svg);
          background-position: 0px -4.5px;
      }

      .switchBar {
          background-color: rgb(102, 34, 25);
          margin: 22px;
          border: solid 2px rgb(66, 4, 4);
          width: 200px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
      }

      .button {
          color: lightblue;
          padding: 5px;
          margin: 2px;
          background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
          display: inline-block;
          border-radius: 8px;
          cursor: pointer;
          border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
          position: left;
      }

      h1 {
          margin: 40px 0 0;
          color: #8a032c;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <div>
    <fieldset>
    <h1>simTest server</h1>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <div v-for="(str, index) in switchObj" v-bind:key="str">
                <div class="switchBar">
                    <div class="switch" v-bind:class="{ closed: this.switchObj[index]==='closed', opened: this.switchObj[index]==='opened' }" @click="onSwitchClick(index)"></div>
                    <div class=" button" @click="onClickClose(index)">close</div>
                    <div class="button" @click="onClickOpen(index)">open</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script>

  const app = new Vue({
    name: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        switchObj: {'K1': 'opened', 'K2': 'opened', 'K3': 'opened'}
      }
    },
    methods: {

      // ONLY for closing relay Button
      onClickClose (myIndex) {
        if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'closed') {
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is already closed.')
        } else if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'opened') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'closed'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now closed.')
        } else {
          console.error('Unknown paramter/s', myIndex)
        }
      },
      // ONLY for opening relay Button
      onClickOpen (myIndex) {
        if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'opened') {
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is already opened.')
        } else if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'closed') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'opened'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now opened.')
        } else {
          console.error('Unknown paramter/s', myIndex)
        }
      },
      // opening AND closing relay by clicking on the image
      onSwitchClick (myIndex) {
        if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'closed') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'opened'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now opened.')
        } else if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'opened') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'closed'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now closed.')
        } else {
          console.error('Unknown paramter/s', myIndex)
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `id` attribute with `app` as value in the root div then in vue instance set `el:"#app"` instead of `name:"#app"` and set `key` to index `v-bind:key="index"` finally
replace `v-bind:class="{ closed: this.switchObj[index]==='closed', opened: this.switchObj[index]==='opened' }"`  by `v-bind:class="{ closed: str==='closed', opened: str==='opened' }"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <title>vue demo</title>     
    <style type="text/css">
    html,
      #app{
        font-family: Helvetica;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1;
        background-color: rgb(221, 229, 230);
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }

      .switch {
          background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          padding: 4px;
          white-space: nowrap;
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 4px;
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          text-align: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: 100%;
          vertical-align: middle;
          margin-right: 20px;
      }

      .switch.closed {
          background: #ee4445;
          background-position: 0px 0px;
      }

      .switch.opened {
          background: #44ee45;
          background-position: 0px -4.5px;
      }

      .switchBar {
          background-color: rgb(102, 34, 25);
          margin: 22px;
          border: solid 2px rgb(66, 4, 4);
          width: 200px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
      }

      .button {
          color: lightblue;
          padding: 5px;
          margin: 2px;
          background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
          display: inline-block;
          border-radius: 8px;
          cursor: pointer;
          border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
          position: left;
      }

      h1 {
          margin: 40px 0 0;
          color: #8a032c;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <div id="app">
    <fieldset>
    <h1>simTest server</h1>
        <hr>
        <div>
              <div v-for="(str, index) in switchObj" v-bind:key="index">
        <div class="switchBar">
          <div class="switch" v-bind:class="{ closed: str==='closed', opened: str==='opened' }" @click="onSwitchClick(index)">{{index}}</div>
          <div class=" button" @click="onClickClose(index)">close</div>
          <div class="button" @click="onClickOpen(index)">open</div>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script>

  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        switchObj: {'K1': 'opened', 'K2': 'opened', 'K3': 'opened'}
      }
    },
    methods: {

      // ONLY for closing relay Button
      onClickClose (myIndex) {
        if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'closed') {
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is already closed.')
        } else if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'opened') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'closed'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now closed.')
        } else {
          console.error('Unknown paramter/s', myIndex)
        }
      },
      // ONLY for opening relay Button
      onClickOpen (myIndex) {
        if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'opened') {
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is already opened.')
        } else if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'closed') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'opened'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now opened.')
        } else {
          console.error('Unknown paramter/s', myIndex)
        }
      },
      // opening AND closing relay by clicking on the image
      onSwitchClick (myIndex) {
        if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'closed') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'opened'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now opened.')
        } else if (this.switchObj[myIndex] === 'opened') {
          this.switchObj[myIndex] = 'closed'
          console.log('onClickClose: Switch ' + myIndex + ' is now closed.')
        } else {
          console.error('Unknown paramter/s', myIndex)
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It works so far, thank you so much!

I now get an error tho: "[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'K1' of undefined""
Apparently, it cannot read my Object switchObj.
I don't wanna be bold but do you have any suggestion for this too?
Again, thank you.

Comment: vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'K1' of undefined"

found in Root, basically in the cdn import, of src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"

Comment: you sir made my day. 
thank you.
Was it because vue tries to access the object before it gets to the data() where the object is referenced?